# Dynamic Syntax Highlighting in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, textmate, tmlanguage

I'm writing an extension for Visual Studio Code which features syntax highlighting for a scripting language. I was able to color many important elements via a TextMate grammar file. There are many lines where I would not know if a captured string refers to a user defined class (for a static call, for instance), or an instance of a class/variable until I perform analysis in code.

Is there a way I can dynamically highlight syntax via code in Visual Studio Code or any alternatives for achieving this?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please share the tmlanguage.json. It will be really helpful for my extension development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is semantic coloring. It is not supported as of VS Code 1.35. You could try to emulate it using [decorators](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/decorator-sample), but the decorators can easily get out of sync with the rest of the highlighting during editing

[This VS Code issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/585) tracks adding semantic coloring to VS Code.

Comment: Thank you. I've looked into decorators and came to the same conclusion, it's a bit messy/hacky if I'm trying to match the static grammar file styles, so I'm going to avoid that. I'll be watching the issue for updates.

Comment: The ticket that Matt mentioned has now been closed: the feature has been released. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Semantic-Highlighting-Overview